# Mongodb find inside sub array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

I have a document that's setup like this:

```js
{
  _id : ObjectId(),
  info : [ 
        [ 
            1399583281000, 
            20.13
        ], 
        [ 
            1399583282000, 
            20.13
        ], 
        [ 
            1399583283000, 
            20.13
        ], 
        [ 
            1399583285000, 
            20.13
        ], 
        [ 
            1399583286000, 
            20.13
        ]
    ]
}
```

This data could be spread across multiple documents.  In general, each document contains data in the info for 59 periods (seconds).

What I would like to do is get all of the info data where the timestamp is greater than a specific time.

Any ideas how I would go about doing this?

Thank you

EDIT:

So, I've found that this seems to return all of the documents:

```js
db.infos.find({
   info:{
      $elemMatch:{
         0:{
            $gt:1399583306000
         }
      }
   }
})
```

But maybe I need to use this in an aggregate query? so that it will return just all the values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your on the right track, but there are a few things to note here, aside from the part that nested arrays ( and especially with anonymous keys) are not exactly a great way to store things, but as long as you consistently know the position then that should be reasonably okay.

There is a distinct difference between matching **documents** and matching *"elements of an array"*. Though your current value would actually not match (your search value is not within the bounds of the document), if the value actually was valid your query correctly matches the *"document"* here, which contains a matching element in the array.

The *"document"* contains **all** of the array elements, even those that do not match, but the condition says the *"document"* does match, so it is returned. If you just want the matching *"elements"* then use [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) instead:

```js
    db.infos.aggregate([
        // Still match the document
        { "$match": { 
            "info": { 
                "$elemMatch": { "0": {"$gte": 1399583285000} }
            }
        }},

        // unwind the array for the matched documents
        { "$unwind": "$info" },

        // Match only the elements
        { "$match": { "info.0": { "$gte": 1399583285000 } } },

        // Group back to the original form if you want
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "info": { "$push": "$info" }
        }}

    ])
```

And that returns just the elements that matched the condition:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("536c1145e99dc11e65ed07ce"),
    "info" : [
            [
                    1399583285000,
                    20.13
            ],
            [
                    1399583286000,
                    20.13
            ]
    ]
}
```

Or course if you only ever expected **one** element to match, then you could simply use projection with `.find()`**:

```js
db.infos.find(
    {
       "info":{
          "$elemMatch":{
             "0": {
                "$gt": 1399583285000
             }
          }
       }
    },
    {
        "info.$": 1
    }
)
```

But with a term like [**`$gt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) you are likely to get multiple hits within a document so the aggregate approach is going to be safer considering that the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator is only going to return the **first** match.

Comment: This is great! One thing I found is it separates by `_id`, it's not one big array containing arrays.

Comment: @dave The "separation" is by the value you use in the `_id` field of the `$group` statement, so it is whatever you want it to be or `null` for everything in the collection. But it seemed to me that you were after filtering this per document. Use as you will.

Comment: I see, can just `null` the `_id`, perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: Any idea how I would add a sort to the `"info.0"` to be desc? I've tried `{ "$sort": { "info.0" : -1 } }` after the group, but no luck.  Thank you

Comment: @dave you probably sorted last. Sort before you `$group`